# How to authorize a GCP project to access a storage bucket owned by another project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using Google Container Registry to build docker images in project A.
To do that it needs to access objects in a bucket owned by project B.
How can I authorize B to have read access on project A's bucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create [Access Control Lists](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists)
 (ACLs) for the buckets in project A. The ACLs can allow a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts) from project B to have read access.

Are you using the Google [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/) or your project A's Cloud Shell? Are you using the [REST API endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/container-analysis/api/reference/rest/)? Whatever the tool/application you are using, access needs to be authorised, so each instruction delivered to your Google Cloud Project is delivered by an account. You can authorise that account to have read access on project A's bucket with ACLs.

Also: data sharing and collaboration scenarios [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/collaboration).